# How can I solve "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be resolved"?

Tags: java, json, jsp, tomcat, jar

When I try to open my jsp through Tomcat, I receive the following messages:

> The type org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
>
> The method getJSONObject() from the type Ejercicio refers to the missing type JSONObject.

I have a java class that goes like this:

```
    package E;
    import org.json.simple.*;
    import javax.json.*;
    import org.json.*;

    public class Ejercicio {
        public int a;
        public String b;

    public Ejercicio (int a, String b) {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        }

    public JSONObject getJSONObject() {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("a", a);
        obj.put("b", b);
        return obj;
        }
    }
```

My jsp goes as follows:

```
    <%@page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@page import="E.Ejercicio"%>
    <%@page import="javax.json.*"%>
    <%@page import="org.json.simple.*"%>
    <%@page import="org.json.*"%>
    <%@page import="net.sf.json.*" %>

    <%  
    ArrayList<Ejercicio> miArray = new ArrayList<Ejercicio>();
    miArray.add(new Ejercicio (1,"Hola"));
    miArray.add(new Ejercicio (2,"Caracola"));
    miArray.add(new Ejercicio (3,"Perola"));
    for (Ejercicio temp:miArray) {
        out.println("<p>"+temp.b+"</p>");
        }

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i=0; i < miArray.size(); i++) {
        jsonArray.put(miArray.get(i).getJSONObject());
        }
    %>
```

I have added a lot of jars to both the lib folder inside WEB-INF and the Tomcat lib trying to solve the problem with no results (commons-beanutils-1.8.1, commons-collections-3.2.1, commons-lang-2.5, commons-logging-1.1.1, ezmorph-1.0.6, java-json, javax.json-1.0, json-lib-2.4-jdk15, json-rpc-1.0, json-simple-1.1.1-sources, org.json).

When I compiled the java class I got the "Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations" message. Could this be related to the jps not compiling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the `json-simple.jar` in your project. 
 
Therefore remove the `import org.json.simple.*`

Secondly, the best practice is to import only the required classes from your jar.Therefore you can replace `import org.json.*;` by

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONString;
```

Answer (score 23):

You are **missing** `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` from your classpath.

if you are using **Maven**, add below into your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Or** you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "from your classpath"? I have added `json-simple-1.1.1`in my project lib and compiled the class again with the following sentence: `javac -cp .;"C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\webapps\Heroismo\WEB-INF\lib\*" Ejercicio.java`, but I get the same error when trying to open the jsp. I don't know Maven.

Answer (score 5):

for me definetely downloded the jar and add it to eclipse simple

just follow these steps 
   1. download the .jar file at this link https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.json
   2. locate and extract the json.jar file

in eclipse 
-right click on your project and go to build path
-add external jar 
-hit apply

that's [image]it ; hope it helps guys

Comment: Additionally: Sometimes the libraries are disabled in the Order and Export tab so the project won't pick them up even if they were added.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I tried adding jar file in the classpath but it was not working for me. If you are using **Java gradle project** than you can try adding these lines in **build.gradle** :

```
implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20220320'
    
implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
```

If you are using **Maven**, add below into your **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220320</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is some version of `json-simple.jar` in your project libs ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Before reading your comment I just had a jar called `json-simple-1.1.1-sources`. Now I have added `json-simple-1.1.1`, but I get the same error when trying to open the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the requisite jar, for me what worked is the downloading of my missing json20140107 jar and adding the import statements as below:

**import org.json.JSONException;**

**import org.json.simple.JSONObject;**

Answer (score 0):

This works for the org.json package:

Copy the source files from here

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Note: this is the source code link (JSON-java) taken from from http://www.json.org/

into \src\org\json folder

In **Eclipse**, click the Open perspective button, then Resource.
[image]

Right click on org.json and then hit Refresh to add the java source code into the project.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the right answer anywhere but my TomCat JSON library problem was with the artifact deployment. If you're using intelliJ, go to project structure >> artifacts and add the jar to your lib folder

Check out my project structure

[image]